# Display information at end of each record not last record-crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to display a footer note at the end of each record.  Most records only span one page so the footer displays at the end of the page.  Although some records span two pages (because of a lot of data) and the footer display on both pages.

What I want is to only have the footer display on the last page if the record spans two pages.

I've placed my information in the page footer but can't figure out how to make it appear on the last page of each record.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in two ways.

1. Use grouping if each record has a unique column. Insert a `Group` for that unique column. You can use `Group Expert` to achieve that. `Hide/suppress` the `Group Header Section` and put your footer information in the `Group Footer Section`.
2. If grouping is not achievable then you can sub-section your `Details Section`. To achieve that `Right click` on your `Details` section and select `Insert Section Below`. A new sub-section under details will be created. Writer your footer information in this sub-section. If there are multiple sub-section of `Details Section` then this footer sub-section must be the last sub-section.

To move your sub-sections / groups up and down you can use options available in `Section Expert`